# my sql code can't check correct if condition

Tags: sql-server

As you can see i have this condition in my query

```
  if lower('HP||2008|201408')=lower(@serial1) or lower('HP||2008|201408')=lower(@serial2)

      select 1
      else select 0
```

[image]

But  the sql skips my condition and return 0 ,but the condition is true .Why ?

All variables are nvarchar(max) data type .

Comment: You should know at this point not to post code in pictures.

Comment: @Lexi i updated .thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, you're comparing 'HP||2008|201408' (one pipe) with serial2 that is equal to 'HP||2008||201408' (two pipes)

(don't know the value of serial1)

Answer (score 1):

The condition is NOT true, that is clear even in the screenshot.

@serial2 does NOT have the same value as what you are checking for - look at it again.